# How to navigate to specific slides via internal links with transition effects

Tags: reveal.js

I'm able to navigate to specific slides using the reveal.js API like so:

```
<script>
    $(document).on('click', '#goToMySlide', function() { Reveal.slide(6); return false; });
</script>
```

But that only jumps directly to the slide without any of the cool transitions that reveal.js is known for (zoom, fade, concave, etc.). Any idea how I can jump to a slide with a transition effect?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you can do this with the `viewDistance` parameter when configuring Reveal.

The author suggests using [`viewDistance: 100`](https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js/issues/260#issuecomment-26919687) (or some sufficiently large number) to make this work.